# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '29/09/2016' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I'm getting error when using Stored procedure.
Below is code of stored procedure:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_specificorderchangedhistory]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
                @startRowIndex int,
    @maximumRows int, 
    @OrderDate datetime= null   
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @first int,@last int
  SET @first = @startRowIndex * @maximumRows
  SET @last = (@startRowIndex * @maximumRows) + @maximumRows
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @sqlcnt varchar(max)
declare @cond varchar(max)

        if @OrderDate is not null 
        begin 
            set @cond = ' and convert(varchar,so.OrderDate,101) ='+convert(varchar,@OrderDate,101)+' ' 
        end
        print @cond
set @sql= 'SELECT * FROM

(

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so.OrderID DESC) AS Row, 

   so.OrderID,

   u1.Firstname+' + ''' ''' + '+u1.Lastname as Username,

   U.Firstname as CustomerName,

   so.OrderNumber,

   so.TotalAmount,

   so.Status,

   so.OrderDate,

   so.Comment,

   p.PaymentMode as PaymentMethod,

   p.PaymentMethod as Payment_Mode,

   p.IsPaid

    FROM SpecificOrders AS so

    INNER join Users as U on so.UserID = U.UserID

    INNER join Users as u1 on so.CreatedBy = u1.UserID       

    INNER join SpecificOrderPayment as p on so.OrderID= p.OrderID  

 '+ @cond +'

) spec

WHERE Row>'+Convert(Varchar,@first )+'  AND 

  Row<='+Convert(Varchar,@last)
print @sql
exec(@sql)
set @sqlcnt= 'SELECT count(*) FROM

(

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so.OrderID DESC) AS Row

    FROM SpecificOrders AS so

    INNER join Users as U on so.UserID = U.UserID

    INNER join Users as u1 on so.CreatedBy = u1.UserID   

    INNER join SpecificOrderPayment as p on so.OrderID= p.OrderID  


 '+ @cond +'

) spec'
exec(@sqlcnt)
end
```

when I'm executing the stored procedure using below query :

```
EXEC usp_specificorderchangedhistory '08/20/2016'
```

Getting error as :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '29/09/2016' to data type int.
```

Although, I tried running same query **without Stored procedure** using

> select

query.It works exactly as per desire:Below is the select query:

```
select * as Dateorder 
from SpecificOrders as s 
inner join SpecificOrderPayment as p 
    on s.OrderID = p.OrderID 
where convert(varchar,s.orderdate,101) =convert(varchar,'08/20/2016',101)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to compare dates by converting them to varchars?

Comment: I tried directly too, it didnt work

Comment: SQL Server understand format `MM/DD/YYY` or`YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: ya in my database , date is saved in the form something like '2016-08-20 14:54:36.363' whereas in query right side of '=' is in the form '08/20/2016'

Comment: Can you elaborate on *I tried directly too, it didnt work* .... you should't be converting a datetime to varchar to do comparisons

Comment: @cond = ' and so.OrderDate ='+convert(varchar,@OrderDate)+' '

Comment: Your problem should explain *why* you shouldn't use string concatenation for query parameters. You avoid SQL injection *and* conversion problems. Since both values are `datetime` you shouldn't need any conversion. Just use `' and so.OrderDate= @someDate ', use `sp_executesql` to execute the final query and pass the value of `@OrderDate` as the `someDate` parameter

Comment: @HinaKhuman how are you trying to use the SQL query? The stored procedure alone makes no sense, you are force to make conversions simply because you need to generate a string. Otherwise you could use `OrderDate = @someDateparam`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Firstly the date saved in my table is in the format '2016-08-20 14:54:36.363' and in this SP is being called via my web page. which sends date in 08/020/2016 format. so I do directly, its not giving result at all

Comment: @HinaKhuman dates have no format. They are binary. Either you use a `datetime` type or text. Which is it? Also the web page should send a full ISO8601 date, not a US only. What has a web page to do with a stored procedure returning a filter condition anyway? You won't avoid any security or conversion problems just because you run the concatenation on the server, on the contrary, you doubled the chances of an injection attack

Comment: Modify your web page code to use parameterized queries and pass actual `DateTime` values instead of strings. You'll probably get rid of a lot of fragile conversion code this way

Comment: `@startRowIndex` is an int, what is the question here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add more quotes and use SELECT:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_specificorderchangedhistory]
        @OrderDate datetime= null   
AS
BEGIN
    declare @cond varchar(max)
    if @OrderDate is not null 
    set @cond = ' and convert(varchar,so.OrderDate,101) ='''+convert(varchar,@OrderDate,101)+'''' 

    SELECT @cond
end

EXEC usp_specificorderchangedhistory '08/20/2016'
```

Output:

```
 and convert(varchar,so.OrderDate,101) ='08/20/2016'
```

**EDIT**

I don't understand why do you use dynamic SQL? All could be done like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_specificorderchangedhistory]
    @startRowIndex int,
    @maximumRows int, 
    @OrderDate datetime= null   
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @first int,
            @last int

    SET @first = @startRowIndex * @maximumRows
    SET @last = (@startRowIndex * @maximumRows) + @maximumRows

    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so.OrderID DESC) AS [Row], 
                so.OrderID,
                u1.Firstname+' '+u1.Lastname as [Username],
                U.Firstname as CustomerName,
                so.OrderNumber,
                so.TotalAmount,
                so.Status,
                so.OrderDate,
                so.Comment,
                p.PaymentMode as PaymentMethod,
                p.PaymentMethod as Payment_Mode,
                p.IsPaid
        FROM SpecificOrders AS so
        INNER join Users as U 
            on so.UserID = U.UserID
        INNER join Users as u1 
            on so.CreatedBy = u1.UserID       
        INNER join SpecificOrderPayment as p 
            on so.OrderID= p.OrderID  
                and so.OrderDate = @OrderDate
    ) spec
    WHERE [Row]>@first  AND [Row]<=@last

    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM (

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so.OrderID DESC) AS [Row]
        FROM SpecificOrders AS so
        INNER join Users as U 
            on so.UserID = U.UserID
        INNER join Users as u1 
            on so.CreatedBy = u1.UserID   
        INNER join SpecificOrderPayment as p 
            on so.OrderID= p.OrderID 
                and so.OrderDate = @OrderDate
    ) spec

end
```

Comment: Same error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '09/29/2016' to data type int.Also, I hv execute as usp_specificorderchangedhistory '08/20/2016' and date in the error is taking date different

Comment: I am using above @cond in other query and ya it get printed as such for ,but does not get executed when using in other query

Comment: You posted all your SP? For me it runs fine.

Comment: How do you use it, please, post.

Comment: @HinaKhuman there is no month 20. In *any* local except the US passing `8/20/2016` will throw a conversion error. You should use culture invariant literals like `YYYYMMDD` for dates, eg `20160820`, or the full ISO8601 form

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly what I was thinking about... Why OP is using `101` style?

Comment: The OP shouldn't. That's just one more problem on top of all the others. Fixing the original query is easy. Fixing *this* procedure that attempts to generate a filter statement is impossible - the double conversions will result in full table scans

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , u may go through site which I used as reference since I was not getting result using direct querying style

http://sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/sqlserverstringtodate/

Comment: @HinaKhuman you don't need *any* conversions if you use parameters. Post the *actual full* query you want to construct, not the code you used to create one of its parts.

Comment: Instead of `exec` use `sp_executesql` and pass the filter values as parameters, as I mentioned in the question comments. You won't need any conversions that way. As it is, it's extremely difficult to fix the procedure *or* avoid SQL Injection attacks

Comment: For example, why `WHERE Row>'+Convert(Varchar,@first )+'  AND ` when you could write `WHERE Row>@first   AND  ROW <=@last ` ?

Comment: Why you even use dynamic SQL?

Comment: I am getting at 'Row' is I remove

Comment: See my edit, try to run it like this. Just specify what to do with `@OrderDate = NULL`

Comment: I works fine , date filter is not added.Rest query is alright without date @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @gofr you don't need the conversions! Just `and so.OrderDate = @OrderDate ` is enough. For the conversions to work, *BOTH* the column and the parameter have to be `datetime`. Why convert then?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for noticing, forgot that, now I removed this conversion.

Comment: My pleasure! :)